# extracting a bit from a buffer

Tags: c++

Whats the best way to extract a bit from an unsigned char .In my opinion ,I think this works perfectly well`

```
int bit;
  unsigned char buffer;
  bit= 1 & (buffer>>3) //`if i want to extract the fourth bit
  bit=  1 & (buffer>>7)//if i want to extract the 8 bit
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it.  Did you have a question?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, you should use `bool bit;`. `bool` is the data type intended for boolean variables, whose values can be either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care for the bit to be in the least significant position (e.g. because you need it for a boolean condition) you can do this:

```
if (buffer & (1<<3)) {
    // ...
}
```

This may be faster because of [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding): it is only one operation at runtime instead of two.

Comment: The code i posted above puts the bit in the least significant bit

Comment: @Jackwelch If you need the bit in the least significant position, your solution is the fastest it gets.